# Rust - How does String::from() actually work?

Tags: rust

I'm still new to rust so there are some stuff about it I still don't know

I'm trying to split a `String` value and pass it to a variable like so:

```
let mut splitted_line = String::from("something=random").split("=");
let key = splitted_line.nth(0).expect("incorrect line format");
let value = splitted_line.nth(1).expect("incorrect line format");
```

The code above raise the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:49:37
   |
49 |             let mut splitted_line = String::from("something=random").split("=");
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                                     |
   |                                     creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
55 |             let key = splitted_line.clone().nth(0).expect("incorrect line format");
   |                       --------------------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Yet (from some reason I still don't know), when I run the code below it works completely fine:

```
let line = String::from("something=random");
let mut splitted_line = line.split("=");
let key = splitted_line.nth(0).expect("incorrect line format");
let value = splitted_line.nth(1).expect("incorrect line format");
```

As far as I read from the Error code [description](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0716). This shouldn't have happened cause I'm not borrowing any value from a variable.

Can someone explain to me why the first code raises the temporary value error and why the second one doesn't?

Comment: Nitpick: you probably want `split_once()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) is borrowing. It takes `&self` and returns an iterator that yields `&str`s referencing `self`.

The difference between the codes is when the splitted string is freed: in the first snippet it is a [*temporary*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html#temporaries) because we invoke a method on it immediately and it is freed at the end of the statement (`let mut splitted_line = String::from("something=random").split("=");`). However, since we use the strings `split()` returned after, and they're borrowing from this freed string, this is an error.

On the second case, the string is not temporary as it is bound to a variable, and it is freed at the end of the scope. Thus, it is still alive when we use `split()` returned strings.

Comment: Ohhhh, now I get it. Thanks !